# Spring Security 4 sessionRegistry doesn't populate Principal list

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement a function where a admin user can terminate another user's session. I followed the official Spring Security documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#list-authenticated-principals and started with getting all currently logged in users through `sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()`, but it always returned an empty list.

I set a breakpoint in SessionRegistryImpl.registerNewSession() and could see it did indeed get invoked and it did add the `UserDetails` (my own implementation with both equals() and hashCode() implemented) to the hashmap `principals`. But when I access sessionRegistry bean from a Spring MVC controller, the list is always empty.

My configuration looks pretty much the same as the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions).

How to fix this? Did anyone successfully get SessionRegistry to work with Spring Security 4? I remember I made it work with Spring Security 3 by following these intructions([enter link description here](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-querying.html))

Comment: I had the exact same problem before, and during optimization of project configuration that issue was fixed automatically for me. However, my entire configuration is for Spring-MVC and not just Spring, and is in XML.

Comment: Let me guess, you are loading the same configuration (classes) twice. Effectivly leading to 2 instances of all the beans including the `SessionRegistry`. Your controller uses a different instance as Spring Security hence it will never receive anything. Fix your configuration, make sure you aren't scanning for the components/configuraiton classes twice.

Comment: Thanks all, that makes a lot of sense to me. I'll investigate the configuration first thing tomorrow, which was previously done by another person.

Comment: @M.Deinum How can I check if a bean is loaded twice ? I have the same issue with an empty list of principals.

Comment: My spring context is explicitly loaded: `<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/my-servlet-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>`

Comment: Let me guess and that is also loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`...

Comment: To check if the sessionRegistry bean was loaded twice I used the debugger, and it breakpoint-ed only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I fixed the issue by cleaning up the Spring configuration files, as suggested by the comments. Someone messed up with the `web.xml` - he added a reference to the context XML that is already referenced by the Spring's `DispatcherServlet`, causing it to be loaded twice. He didn't know it, because Spring references the file implicitly.

P.S.
I learned my lessons, but 2 things the Spring folks could do better (maybe in Spring 5?):

1. There shouldn't be implicit context file loading. Currently, the framework will try to load the application context from a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml located in the application's WebContent/WEB-INF directory. Convention over configuration fails in this case.
2. There should be warning when a bean is loaded twice, if someone need to override a bean definition, he must declare explicitly. Otherwise it would take a lot of time to debug the kind of error this mistake will cause.

Comment: I suppose having an explicit loading of the Spring context does NOT count as a double loading `<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/my-servlet-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>`